# How to read data from multiple firebase databases?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sharding

I am working on Android app that allows users to read data from multiple Firebase databases.

For some reasons the data is not sorted by date and come in random order. How can I sort comments by date and show latest one at the bottom of the list?

```
ArrayList<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
    comments.add(comment):
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    Comment newComment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
    String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    Comment movedComment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
    String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
}
};


  List<String> dbUris = getFirebaseUriList();
    for(String dburi: dbUris){
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(dburi).getReference().child("comments").limitToLast(15);
        query.addChildEventListener(listener);

    }
```

Is it a good idea to use the same listener on multiple queries? Thank you.

Comment: please upload a sample screenshot of your database

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
  query.addChildEventListener(listener);
```

into this:

```
 query.orderByChild("date").addChildEventListener(listener);
```

to be able to sort the data by `date`

more info here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query